# Can "connect by" do running calculations when creating a hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, oracle18c

I am trying to create a query that can create a hierarchy of occurrences in my data. However, since each production record can have several occurrences I need to create a weight for each hierarchy so I know which one is correct and can later filter for the specified result.

This weight would be the sum of the distance for each node defined as the sum of the absolute value of the difference between initiation and occurrence.

Had there been a perfect relationship between initiation and occurrence I would have used it as a criteria in the connect by statement, but as it's not the case I wondered if it is at all possible to sum the absolute value of each node so I can get an "accuracy" measure to use as a filtering column for further analysis?

##### Data

| PROD | MGRID | init | occ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NULL | 2001/1/1 | 2016/4/12 |
| 100 | NULL | 2001/1/1 | 2017/2/11 |
| 100 | NULL | 2001/1/1 | 2017/7/19 |
| 101 | 100 | 2017/2/11 | 2017/2/21 |
| 102 | 100 | 2017/2/11 | 2017/2/11 |
| 103 | 100 | 2016/5/12 | 2016/5/12 |
| 201 | 103 | 2016/5/12 | 2016/5/12 |
| 202 | 101 | 2017/2/20 | 2017/2/21 |
| 203 | 100 | 2017/7/20 | 2017/7/19 |

##### Current Code

```sql
SELECT
    prod, mgrid, init, occ, level AS lvl, sys_connect_by_path(prod, '/') AS path
FROM mytab
WHERE level > 1
START WITH
    mgrid IS NULL
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR prod = mgrid
ORDER BY
    prod;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your expected output for that sample data.

Comment: `connect by` does not provide access to intermediate results, so you need a recursive subquery for this.

Comment: Thank you @astentx, I was afraid of that as I could not find any information supporting the possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH data (prod, mgrid, init, occ, lvl, path, weight) AS (
  SELECT prod,
         mgrid,
         init,
         occ,
         1,
         '/' || prod,
         ABS(occ-init)
  FROM   mytab
  WHERE  mgrid IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT m.prod,
         m.mgrid,
         m.init,
         m.occ,
         lvl + 1,
         d.path || '/' || m.prod,
         d.weight + ABS(m.occ - m.init)
  FROM   mytab m
         INNER JOIN data d
         ON (d.prod = m.mgrid)
)
SELECT *
FROM   data
WHERE  lvl > 1
ORDER BY prod;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytab (PROD, MGRID, init, occ) AS
SELECT 100, NULL, DATE '2001-01-01', DATE '2016-04-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, NULL, DATE '2001-01-01', DATE '2017-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, NULL, DATE '2001-01-01', DATE '2017-07-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 100,  DATE '2017-02-11', DATE '2017-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 100,  DATE '2017-02-11', DATE '2017-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 100,  DATE '2016-05-12', DATE '2016-05-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 103,  DATE '2016-05-12', DATE '2016-05-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202, 101,  DATE '2017-02-20', DATE '2017-02-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 203, 100,  DATE '2017-07-20', DATE '2017-07-19' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PROD | MGRID | INIT | OCC | LVL | PATH | WEIGHT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 101 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/101 | 5590 |
> | 101 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/101 | 6053 |
> | 101 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/101 | 5895 |
> | 102 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 11-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/102 | 5580 |
> | 102 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 11-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/102 | 6043 |
> | 102 | 100 | 11-FEB-17 | 11-FEB-17 | 2 | /100/102 | 5885 |
> | 103 | 100 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 2 | /100/103 | 5580 |
> | 103 | 100 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 2 | /100/103 | 6043 |
> | 103 | 100 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 2 | /100/103 | 5885 |
> | 201 | 103 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 3 | /100/103/201 | 5580 |
> | 201 | 103 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 3 | /100/103/201 | 6043 |
> | 201 | 103 | 12-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-16 | 3 | /100/103/201 | 5885 |
> | 202 | 101 | 20-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 3 | /100/101/202 | 6054 |
> | 202 | 101 | 20-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 3 | /100/101/202 | 5896 |
> | 202 | 101 | 20-FEB-17 | 21-FEB-17 | 3 | /100/101/202 | 5591 |
> | 203 | 100 | 20-JUL-17 | 19-JUL-17 | 2 | /100/203 | 5581 |
> | 203 | 100 | 20-JUL-17 | 19-JUL-17 | 2 | /100/203 | 5886 |
> | 203 | 100 | 20-JUL-17 | 19-JUL-17 | 2 | /100/203 | 6044 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88afa3db758dd37d7bb0bb7d9f94adbc)*